# Length of elements of a list in right format

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have the following list:

```
l=[[["a", "b", "c", "k"], ["a", "b", "c", "s", "u"], ["a", "b", "f", "t"], ["a", "b", "e", "l", "n", "o"]],[["a", "b", "d", "n", "o"], ["a","b", "d", "e", "n", "o"]]]
```

I want to go through each element and find the length to do this did the following:

```
s=[]
for i in l:
    for j in i:
        s.append(len(j))
```

which gives me the length correctly as follow:

```
[4, 5, 4, 6, 5, 6]
```

However `l` itself has length 2 so I want my output to look like the follow:

```
[[4, 5, 4, 6],[5, 6]]
```

I wonder why does this flattening happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *nested list comprehension* in order to preserve the nested structure:

```
[[len(j) for j in i] for i in l]
#[[4, 5, 4, 6], [5, 6]]
```

---

If you prefer a for loop, you could initialize the nested list beforehand taking into account the length of `l`, and use `enumerate` to `append` to each sublist:

```
s = [[] for i in range(len(l))]
for ix, i in enumerate(l):
    for j in i:
        s[ix].append(len(j))
```

Comment: Thanks that nested list comprehension was very short and neat :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
l=[[["a", "b", "c", "k"], ["a", "b", "c", "s", "u"], ["a", "b", "f", "t"], ["a", "b", "e", "l", "n", "o"]],[["a", "b", "d", "n", "o"], ["a","b", "d", "e", "n", "o"]]]
s=[]
for i in l:
    subList=[]
    for j in i:
        subList.append(len(j))
    s.append(subList)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but you could define a recursive function to apply a given function to the lowest-level sublists in a given list of lists, i.e. to all sublists that are not entirely composed of other lists. This will also work with more levels of nesting, irregularly nested lists, and with other function than `len`.

```
def deep_map(f, lst):
    if all(type(x) == list for x in lst):
        # call recursively for nested sublists
        return [deep_map(f, x) for x in lst]
    else:
        # apply to this sublist
        return f(lst)
```

In your case, call as `deep_map(len, l)` to get `[[4, 5, 4, 6], [5, 6]]`.